# SVN new folder structure check out

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I have changed folder structure in svn repository. Because of that Ineed to delete the previous check out folder and check out new directory structure. But after deleting it ,the check out is disabled.

How to completely delete it and get a fresh copy? I have also done clean up.But not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the ENTIRE working copy, including the top-level folder, you should have a checkout option. Checkout should be available in any directory where you don't already have a working copy.

But you may not have actually needed to delete your working copy in the first place. If your working copy points to some parent of the reorganization, you only needed to `svn update`. If your old working copy is pointing to a folder that got renamed or moved, you can use `svn switch`.